# how to check for duplicate inputs and prevents it to be added to the database

Tags: java, mysql

Hello guys how can I check duplicate inputs (adding students) and how to prevent it. It says that when i create a table the inputs that I've been inserting the database is all a duplicate which is obviously not. In line with that how can I detect and check of the inserted input is a duplicate of the previous inputs.[This is the first output in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFTjW.png) [This is the continuation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaofG.png)

Here is my code:

Main.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
//import java.sql.ResultSet;
//import java.sql.SQLException;
//import java.sql.Statement;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    StudentDAO x1= new StudentDAO();
        x1.getConnection();
        x1.makeTable(); //create Table
        x1.addstud("1","Yves Francisco", "2000000001","5","CpE","Male");
        x1.addstud("2","Lance Eco", "2000000002","5","CpE","Male");
        x1.addstud("3","Karlos Castillo", "2000000003","5","CpE","Male");
        x1.addstud("4","Glenn Bordonada", "2000000004","5","ECE","Male");
        x1.addstud("5","JM Enriquez", "2000000005","5","ECE","Male");
        x1.addstud("6","John Martinez", "2000000006","2","ECE","Male");
        x1.addstud("7","Timothy Tolentino", "2000000007","4","IT","Male");
        x1.addstud("8","Kyle Dacaymat", "2000000008","3","CpE","Male");
        x1.addstud("9","Dom Benedictos", "2000000009","1","IT","Male");
        x1.addstud("10","Lance Roque", "2000000010","1","ECE","Male"); 
        x1.addstud("11", "Vegeta", "2000000011", "1", "ME", "Male"); // added Student
        //x1.addstud("12", "Vegeta", "2000000011", "1", "ME", "Male"); // pang check if entered input is a duplicate of a field of studName, studNumber, etc.
        //x1.delstud(); // delete student
        //x1.updstuddb();
        x1.showdb();
}
```

}

StudentDAO.java

```
//import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
//import java.sql.ArrayList;
```

public class StudentDAO {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void showdb() throws Exception
{


    try {


        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT *FROM studinfo;";            
        PreparedStatement showstuddb= con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = showstuddb.executeQuery();


        System.out.println("Showing Database.....................");
        System.out.println("============================================================@ THE CONTENT OF THE DATABASE @============================================================");
        while (rs.next()) 

        {
            String idko = rs.getObject(1).toString();
            String ngalan = rs.getObject(2).toString();
            String numko=rs.getObject(3).toString();
            String baitang=rs.getObject(4).toString();
            String kurso=rs.getObject(5).toString();
            String kasarian=rs.getObject(6).toString();


            System.out.println("My ID number is: "+ idko + "  Name is: " + ngalan + "  Student Number is: " + numko + "  Year/Level is: "+ baitang +"  Course is: " + kurso + "  Sex is: " + kasarian);


        }

        showstuddb.close();
        System.out.println("Nothing follows.....................");
        con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error on showing contents of database!!!" + e.getMessage());
    }


}



public void updstuddb () throws Exception
{

    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "UPDATE studinfo SET studName=?, studNum=?, studYrLvl=?, studKors=?, studGender=? WHERE studid=?";
        PreparedStatement studup = con.prepareStatement(query);

        studup.setString(1, "Kakarot"); //This will be the replacement
        studup.setString(2, "2000000020");
        studup.setString(3, "2"); 
        studup.setString(4, "IT");
        studup.setString(5, "dafq");
        studup.setString(6, "1");// The unique element among the content of the database which is used to determine which is to update

        studup.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("THE LIST HAS BEEN UPDATED @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        studup.close();
        con.close();
    }



    catch (Exception e)     
    {
        System.out.println("Error in updating the database!!!" + e.getMessage());

    }

}

public void delstud() 
{
    try {
    Connection con = getConnection();

    String query = "DELETE FROM studinfo WHERE studid=?";
    PreparedStatement userdel = con.prepareStatement(query);

    userdel.setString(1, "12"); // To determine what to delete in the Database
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000002");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000003");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000004");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000005");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000006");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000007");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000008");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000009");
    //userdel.setString(1, "2000000010");

    userdel.execute();
    userdel.close();
    System.out.println("Data is now deleted!!!");
    con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error!!!. Data is not deleted " + e.getMessage());

    }

}


public  void addstud(String studid, String studName, String studNum, String studYrLvl, String studKors, String studGender) throws Exception 
{

    //String var1 = "Yves Francisco";
    //String num1 = "2000000001";
    //String num2 = "5";
    //String var2 = "CpE";
    //String var3 = "Male";

    try {

        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement posted= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO studinfo (studid, studName, studNum, studYrLvl, studKors, studGender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");


        int y=1;
        posted.setString(y++, studid);
        posted.setString(y++, studName);
        posted.setString(y++, studNum);
        posted.setString(y++, studYrLvl);
        posted.setString(y++, studKors);
        posted.setString(y++, studGender);

        posted.executeUpdate(); // Manipulate or Update table
        posted.close();
        //con.close();

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error on adding columns!!!" + e.getMessage());
    }

    finally 
    {
        System.out.println("Insert Successful!");   

    }

    //FOR DUPLICATE INPUTS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    try 
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT studName, studNum, studYrLvl, studKors, studGender FROM studinfo WHERE studName=?, studNum=?, studYrLvl=?, studKors=?, studGender=?";
        PreparedStatement checkdup = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs=checkdup.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            boolean dup1=rs.getObject(2).equals(studName);
            boolean dup2=rs.getObject(3).equals(studNum);
            boolean dup3=rs.getObject(4).equals(studYrLvl);
            boolean dup4=rs.getObject(5).equals(studKors);
            boolean dup5=rs.getObject(6).equals(studGender);

            System.out.println("The name you entered is: " + dup1 + " The student number you entered is: " + dup2 + " The Yr/Lvl you entered: " + dup3 + " The Course you entered: " + dup4 + " The Sex you entered is: " + dup5);


        }


        con.close();


    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("You entered a duplicate value!!. Try Again! ");
        System.out.println("Take note that the entered Duplicate value is entered in the Database");
        System.out.println("Remove the duplicate value using delstud() method!!!");

    }

}

public void makeTable() throws Exception
{

    try
    {
        Connection con= getConnection();
        PreparedStatement create = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studinfo (studid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, studName varchar(255), studNum varchar(30), studYrLvl varchar(2), studKors varchar(30), studGender varchar(10));");

        create.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("TABLE IS CREATED!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        create.close();
        con.close();
    }


    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error on creating table!!. Table not created!"+e.getMessage());

    }

    finally 
    {
        System.out.println("Table created!");
    };
}

public  Connection getConnection () throws Exception {
        try {

            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
            String username= "root";
            String password = "root";
            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("You are now Connected!!");
            return conn; // Return if it is successfully connected!



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Connection not Established!"+e.getMessage());
        }


        return null; // Return if unsuccessful
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not a duplicate value in your table, the problem is that you have a mistake in your code. 
I wouldn't do it the way you do, because if you use a Try-Catch, anyway there is a problem or a mistake in your code (looking for duplicates) it will answer that you have a duplicate.
Otherwise, even if you have thousands of duplicates, if you don't get an error you won't get a duplicate.

Anyways, the mistake you have in your code is that you don't give any value to the checkdup prepared statement, you should change it to something like this:

```
   //FOR DUPLICATE INPUTS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   try 
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT studName, studNum, studYrLvl, studKors, studGender FROM studinfo WHERE studName=?, studNum=?, studYrLvl=?, studKors=?, studGender=?";
        PreparedStatement checkdup = con.prepareStatement(query);
        checkdup.setString(1, studName);
        checkdup.setString(2, studNum);
        checkdup.setString(3, studYrLvl);
        checkdup.setString(4, studKors);
        checkdup.setString(5, studGender);   

        ResultSet rs=checkdup.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            boolean dup1=rs.getObject(2).equals(studName);
            boolean dup2=rs.getObject(3).equals(studNum);
            boolean dup3=rs.getObject(4).equals(studYrLvl);
            boolean dup4=rs.getObject(5).equals(studKors);
            boolean dup5=rs.getObject(6).equals(studGender);

            System.out.println("The name you entered is: " + dup1 + " The student number you entered is: " + dup2 + " The Yr/Lvl you entered: " + dup3 + " The Course you entered: " + dup4 + " The Sex you entered is: " + dup5);

        }  

        con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("You entered a duplicate value!!. Try Again! ");
        System.out.println("Take note that the entered Duplicate value is entered in the Database");
        System.out.println("Remove the duplicate value using delstud() method!!!");

    }
```

**EDIT**

There is an easy way to look for duplicates, you just count how many you have like in this code:

```
   //FOR DUPLICATE INPUTS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   try 
    {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT studName, studNum, studYrLvl, studKors, studGender FROM studinfo WHERE studName=?, studNum=?, studYrLvl=?, studKors=?, studGender=?";
        PreparedStatement checkdup = con.prepareStatement(query);
        checkdup.setString(1, studName);
        checkdup.setString(2, studNum);
        checkdup.setString(3, studYrLvl);
        checkdup.setString(4, studKors);
        checkdup.setString(5, studGender);   

        ResultSet rs=checkdup.executeQuery();
    int dup=0;
        while (rs.next())
        {
        dup+=1;
        }  

    if (dup>1 ) {
        System.out.println("You entered a duplicate value!!. Try Again! ");         
        System.out.println("Take note that the entered Duplicate value is entered in the Database");
        System.out.println("Remove the duplicate value using delstud() method!!!");
    }

        con.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("There is an error ");

    }
```

In your INSERT statement, you also need to change things. The `studid` is an autoincrement column, so you don't have to put it in your INSERT. It should be like:

```
    Connection con = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement posted= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO studinfo (studName, studNum, studYrLvl, studKors, studGender) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

    int y=1;
    posted.setString(y++, studName);
    posted.setString(y++, studNum);
    posted.setString(y++, studYrLvl);
    posted.setString(y++, studKors);
    posted.setString(y++, studGender);

    posted.executeUpdate(); // Manipulate or Update table
    posted.close();
```

Comment: thanks bro for your efforts, how can i integrate it if there are a duplicate inputs then. Also, i get these error/s:


com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' studNum='2000000011', studYrLvl='1', studKors='ME', studGender='Male'' at line 1

Comment: thanks bro FINALLY!, welp i cant find any source as good as that little if statement you gave. thanks very mcuh for the help!